# Passing variables from apex to javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, json

I'm trying to get data from apex which is in this form `Map<String1, List<Map<String2,String3>>>` 
to use it in javascript before returning a result to the apex controller..

I have tried to do it this way but my webpage keep refreshing and the content of my variable is 'false' ( I have figured this out by using console.log(myVariable); )

```
 <apex:actionFunction action="{!myApexMethod}" name="getResult"/>

 <script>
   var res = getResult();
   console.log(res);
 </script>
```

**Controller code..**

```
public String jsonResult{get; set;} 
public Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>> myData  = getResult(); 

public void getResult(){
        jsonResult = JSON.serialize(myData);
    }
```

It's just a little part the getResult() method is so long to write here.. but you can see what type of object it returns..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After storing the results of the myApexMethod in a property in your controller this will rerender the script block and get the updated value
This should work:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!myApexMethod}" name="getResult" rerender="script_block"/>

<apex:outPutPanel layout="block" id="script_block">
 <script>
   var res = "{!controller_property}";
   console.log(res);
 </script>
</apex:outPutPanel>
```

**You would be better served using Visualforce Remoteing for these types of things though.**

Comment: If you're going to use the method here from Eric, make sure that you escape your string for JS using '{!JSENCODE(controller_property}'. Otherwise you'll get tripped up by Irish names and so on (O'Hara etc).

Comment: I have tried that but still I don't have the right content.. the result is null

Comment: @JoeyPablo - you will have to post the relevant part of your controller code in order to assist any more

Comment: @Eric okay i'll edit my question right now to add some of my controller code